# Is there a non-commercial alternative to Z.EntityFramework.Extensions?

Tags: c#, sql-update, entity-framework-6, sql-insert, sql-delete

Entity Framework can be very slow on mass insert/update/delete operations. Even the often suggested tweaks to turn off AutoDetectChanges and/or ValidateOnSaveEnabled does not always help.

I have come across the Z.EntityFramework.Extensions on NuGet, but it seems to be a commercial product, which will only work for a certain period of time.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Extensions/

So far, I really only need BulkInsert(), BulkUpdate() and BulkDelete().

**My question is:**

***Is there any reliable non-commercial library, that does nearly the same as Z.EntityFramework.Extensions?***

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: For batch update and delete you can use https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended. For batch insert - just create new context every 100 or so entities. So create context, insert 100, save changes. Then create new one, insert next 100, save changes etc. Wrap all that in transaction scope. That's not really batch insert but will be much faster than inserting all entities in the same context instance.

Comment: ORMs in general are *NOT* suitable for batch operations, much less bulk inserts. It's like using tweezers to transport a truckload of pebbles. You can't cover this up with any extension. The best option for bulk inserts is to use SqlBulkCopy to perform a *real*, minimally logged, streaming bulk insert operation. If you want to perform bulk updates, just use the appopriate UPDATE statement. If you want to *UPSERT* from external sources, import everything into a staging table and use MERGE to update the target table

Comment: In other words, you are looking for something that can convert an unbreliable, unsafe, non-scaleable process to a reliable one. Why not use the reliable, scaleable process from the start?

Comment: @Evk I have tested that method and it is still too slow.

Comment: You mean inserts are slow? And what about that library you mentioned? How much faster is bulk insert there?

Comment: @Evk On SQL-Server 5000 inserts or deletes it is about 15-20 seconds. I disabled AutoDetect and AutoValidate and created a new context very 100 items. With the mentioned library it is less then 2 seconds.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, I came up with the same question and now I had found this: 
- https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions with MIT license.
With 4.62 million downloads, it has more downloads than the Z.EntityFramework.Extensions meanwhile.

Comment: @JanaWeschenfelder, EFCore.BulkExtensions is no longer free... It costs between $500-$4000 for an enterprise: https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/issues/1079

Comment: @Jonathan Magnan I do not work on that project anymore, so it does not matter to me personally anymore. And if I should I have the problem sometime in the future again: EF Core became significantly faster the past years, and then there is still Dapper. Large companies use other stuff in the main today, like Messaging Queues, e.g. RabbitMQ and Apache Kafka e.g. in combination with Elasticsearch. ;-)

Comment: [EF Core Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) page lists a lot of tools. I liked [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

You are right. This is a commercial product.

*Every month, a free trial is available, but you will have to purchase the product for the production environment.*

**Bulk Insert**

For BulkInsert, there are some free alternatives but be careful, they don't support all inheritances & associations and are no longer supported:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert-ef6
- https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

For Batch Update && Batch Delete, you can use this library:

```
// DELETE all users which has been inactive for 2 years
ctx.Users.Where(x => x.LastLoginDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2))
         .Delete();

// UPDATE all users which has been inactive for 2 years
ctx.Users.Where(x => x.LastLoginDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2))
         .Update(x => new User() { IsSoftDeleted = 1 });
```

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan. I will mark this as a valid answer, because I think, as the owner of such a product, you have a good overview on other competitors. Really sad, that there is no insert in EF Plus, but I guess there has to be some distinction to the commercial product.

Comment: Unfortunately, we tried to offer some open source features, but this business model just cannot work. So yes, we need some distinction between both libraries. Open source/free projects most of the time fail at being supported after a time because the cost/time/complexity keep being dramatically increased as more users use it. By example, last year, this free library took us more time to support than our other libraries combined!

Comment: Hi Michael, just wondering if you came across SqlBulkTools during your research?

Comment: @JonathanMagnan You are a life saver man , but I think you can add more sale plans

Comment: Hello, @sepehr, you can contact us directly if you have some suggestions, we will be happy to analyze your idea with you and see if that could work.

Comment: As of version 1.8.11 TPH & TPC still don't work. And it has been requested for years. Very unreliable. I would not count on the code of this program.

Comment: @N73k, It already works on `Entity Framework Extensions`. Very soon, "Batch Update" and "Batch Delete" will be free in `EFE`

Comment: No, it doesn't work completely. For example, Delete & DeleteFromQuery don't work with TPT - only the top level table is affected.

Comment: Not the better place to provide support but feel free to send your example that doesn't work: info@zzzprojects.com, we will add support to them.

Comment: zzzprojects stuff fo EF is great but it doesn't mix with unit tested code :(

Comment: Hello Ian, it now works great with Effort: https://entityframework-effort.net/

Comment: @JonathanMagnan: I am confused about licensing. The page at (https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/PRO-License) says: "PRO License
Jonathan Magnan edited this page on Sep 12, 2018 · 3 revisions
No setup required. The Entity Framework Plus library is FREE!"

Comment: I'd like to know too, i have installed the plugin but i can't find any trial info on my project and I'd like to make sure i can use it for production

Comment: If you landed here, this is worth a look (has MIT license) --> https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

Comment: @IdusOrtus EFCore.BulkExtensions is no longer free... It costs between $500-$4000 for an enterprise: https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/issues/1079